# Как в SVG сгруппировать объект

Tags: html5, svg, svg-спрайт

Не могу понять, как сгруппировать объект, так чтобы можно было бы повторять конструкцию приведенную ниже для большего количества SVG разных, но подобных по размерам картинок?

```html
<svg width='100%' height='100%'
     viewBox="0 0 1024 543" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
    <defs>
        <symbol id='big' viewBox="0 0 70 500"><polyline points="15 15 5 10 15 5" stroke="crimson" fill="none" stroke-width="3"/></symbol>
        <symbol id='small' viewBox="0 0 70 80"><polyline points="15 15 5 10 15 5" stroke="crimson" fill="none" stroke-width="3"/></symbol>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#big" />
    <use xlink:href="#small" />
</svg>
```

В теге   `<symbol id='small'` `viewBox="0 0 70 80">` и  `<symbol id='big'` `viewBox="0 0 70 500">` 
Различия идут только лишь в двух последних цифрах. Внутреннее наполнение одинаковое.

Как сделать так чтобы  можно было повторно использовать этот класс через `<use>`?

Comment: не совсем ясно что надо сделать !

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский Я видимо не совсем понимаю как правильно управлять 1 масштабом. 2 polyline один и тот же для одного рисунка и для другого разница в масштабе. 

Вопрос как сделать так что бы можно было использовать вставку  <use xlink:href="какой то класс " /> что бы можно было применять для других  polyline?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду вставлять use за пределами svg ?

Comment: или вызывать use по class ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский дело в том что мне нужно вставлять посути всё что лежит в теге <svg поскольку тут размеры окна браузера> <symbol> тут шаблон  </symbol> здесь вставить шаблон только 2 раза и тут меняется только высота </svg> походу если по ID вызывать то разные значения в шаблоне перебиваются на одно и то же значение Значит класс нужно использовать. Вот такая у меня беда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно пойти по другому пути. Использовать один `<polyline>` и вызывать его многократно с помощью команды `<use>`.

- Для получения любого размера галочки использовать команду `scale(X)`

```html
<svg width='50%' height='50%' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     viewBox="0 0 1024 543" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid red" >
    <defs>
        <symbol id='small' viewBox="0 0 70 80"><polyline points="15 15 5 10 15 5" stroke="crimson" fill="none" stroke-width="3"/></symbol>
    </defs>
    
    <use xlink:href="#small" transform="scale(0.25)" />
  <use xlink:href="#small" transform="scale(0.45)" /> 
  <use xlink:href="#small" transform="scale(0.7)" />
  <use xlink:href="#small" transform="scale(1)" />
</svg>
```

- Для позиционирования галочки добавить команду `translate(X Y)`

  В примере ниже я разместил все 4 галочки у левого края по вертикали

```html
<svg width='50%' height='50%' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     viewBox="0 0 1024 543" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid red" >
    <defs>
        <symbol id='small' viewBox="0 0 70 80"><polyline points="15 15 5 10 15 5" stroke="crimson" fill="none" stroke-width="3"/></symbol>
    </defs>
    
    <use xlink:href="#small"  transform="translate(-50 0) scale(0.25)"  />
  <use xlink:href="#small" transform="translate(-120 30) scale(0.5)" /> 
  <use xlink:href="#small" transform="translate(-180 100) scale(0.7)" />
  <use xlink:href="#small" transform="translate(-270 200) scale(1)"  />
 
</svg>
```